# What are the properties of these two functions?

Tags: combinatorics, special-functions, summation

OK, so I was kinda doodling stuff in my free time and I came up with these two functions:

$$C_1(n) = \sum^{\infty}_{k = n} {{k \choose n}^{-1}}$$
$$C_2(n) = \sum^{n}_{k = 0} {{n \choose k}^{-1}}$$

I don't have Mathematica or anything at the moment, so I can't analyse these functions as such. Would anyone help me out with the properties of these functions (convergence etc.)?

Comment: If you have a lot of free time perhaps you might try to improve your language too?

Comment: @Ad. : I'd like to know which aspect of my language needs improvement.

Comment: Sorry if I hurt your feelings, it was not my intention to be mean. Actually, I am quiet sure your English is far much better than mine! It is however a good thing to avoid chat language outside of chats and spoken language when writing.

Comment: In addition I would like to say that the mathematics of the question is fine.

Comment: No offense taken :-)

Comment: I am glad to hear that, I hope you see my point too :)

Comment: For the first function, see also [A proof for the identity $\sum_{n=r}^{\infty} {n \choose r}^{-1} = \frac{r}{r-1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2124113#comment4368588_2124251)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first series is divergent for $\,n\le 1\;$ and convergent for larger values to  :
$$C_1(n)=\sum^{\infty}_{k = n} \frac {n!}{\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}}=\sum^{\infty}_{j= 1}\frac{n!}{\frac{(j+n-1)!}{(j-1)!}}=\sum^{\infty}_{j= 1}\frac{n!}{(j)_n}=\frac {n!}{(n-1)(n-1)!}$$
where $\;(j)_n=\dfrac {(j+n-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ is the ['rising' Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) and where we used the equation $(19)$ from the link at the limit $n\to\infty\;$  to get : $\;\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{(k)_p}=\frac 1{(p-1)(p-1)!}$.

The result is simply :$$\boxed{\displaystyle C_1(n)=\frac n{n-1},\quad\text{for }\ n>1}$$

---

A generating function for $C_2$ is (from OEIS [A046825](https://oeis.org/A046825)) :
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_2(n)\;z^n&=\left[\frac {2\,\ln(1 - z)}{z-2}\right]'=\frac 2{(z-1)(z-2)}-\frac{2\;\ln(1-z)}{(z-2)^2}\\
&=1+2\;z+\frac 52z^2+\frac 83z^3+\frac 83z^4+\frac {13}5z^5+\frac{151}{60}z^6+\cdots\\
\end{align}

Comment: Glad you liked it @AD.!

Comment: @RaymondManzoni That's enough to get me started. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome @SohamChowdhury !