# A proof for the identity $\sum_{n=r}^{\infty} {n \choose r}^{-1} = \frac{r}{r-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Do you have any idea to prove the following identity via a combinatorial (or algebraic) method? 
$\sum_{n=r}^{n=\infty} {n \choose r}^{-1} = \frac{r}{r-1}$

This is [Exercise 71 in Chapter 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=gFo4LJmSe6gC&pg=PA112) of the book Chen C.C., Koh K.M. Principles and techniques in combinatorics. The book does not give a solution, although it mentions: "see H. W. Gould, *Combinatorial Identities*, Morgantown, W.V. (1972), 18-19".

many thanks in advance,
Shahram

Comment: have you spend one or two own thoughts on it?

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that $${n\choose k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1x^{n-k}(1-x)^k\mathrm dx$$

Comment: What is the source of the problem? What is $r$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : this is an exercice (of the second chapter) from the book "Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics".

Comment: @tired : of course I did!!! For instance, I tried to use the identity ${n \choose k} = \frac{n}{k} {n-1 \choose k-1}$ but I didn't get anything interesting.

Comment: I don't think the result is true

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Sorry, the lower bound of the summation starts from $n=r$ (rather than $n=1$). I modified it.

Comment: @polfosol thank you very much for your idea. I will try to use the identity that you suggest.

Comment: Mathematica agrees with the proposed formula, so I think we can focus on trying to show it.

Comment: This sum is also mentioned in the question: [What are the properties of these two functions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/466696) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3Dr%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20r%7D%5E%7B-1%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: In general, it is advised to [include context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) of your question. One of things which should be included is the source of the problem. (In this case, I have added information about the source to your post based on your comments.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Your are absolutely right! thanks for adding the comments on the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is basically a generalization of the approach from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662784/finding-the-sum-to-n-terms-of-series-frac11-cdot-2-cdot-3-cdot-4-frac1/1662806#1662806):
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=r}^\infty \frac1{\binom nr} 
&= r! \sum_{n=r}^\infty \frac1{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}\\
&= \frac{r!}{r-1} \sum_{n=r}^\infty \frac{n-(n-r+1)}{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}\\
&= \frac{r!}{r-1} \sum_{n=r}^\infty \left(\frac1{(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)} - \frac1{n(n-1)\dots(n-r+2)}\right)\\
&\overset{(1)}= \frac{r!}{r-1} \cdot \frac1{(r-1)!} = \\
&= \frac{r}{r-1}
\end{align*}

The equation $(1)$ is based on the fact that we get a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) and with the exception of the first term, all remaining terms "cancel out".

The above works only for $r\ne1$. But it is clear that for $r=1$ we get the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$, which [is divergent](//math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge).

---

To explain this more clearly, we have a sum of the form $$\sum_{r=n}^\infty (a_n-a_{n+1})= (a_r-a_{r+1})+ (a_{r+1}-a_{r+2})+\dots.$$ Since $a_n\to 0$, we get that the sum is simply $a_r$, since the partial sum is $$\sum_{r=n}^N (a_n-a_{n+1}) = (a_r-a_{r+1})+(a_{r+1}-a_{r+2})+\dots+(a_N-a_{N+1}) = a_r-a_{N+1}.$$ In our case $a_n=1/[(n-1)\cdots(n-r)]$.

---

After some rewriting, we can see that this is a sum which has been calculated on this site a few times, [namely $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k(k+1)\cdots(k+s)}$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac1%7Bk(k%2B1)%5Ccdots(k%2Bs)%7D%24&p=1). In our case, $s=r-1$. (Clearly, when I was trying to search for it before posting my answer, I did not choose the correct search queries.) A few posts about this sum found using the above search in Approach0:

- [How do I evaluate this limit: $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdots(k+m)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103255/how-do-i-evaluate-this-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kk1)
- [How do we calculate this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+p)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306921/how-do-we-calculate-this-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nn1-cdotsnp)
- [Calculate the infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+p)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004004/calculate-the-infinite-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac1kk1k2-cdots-kp)
- [How to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)} = \frac{1}{kk!}$ for every $k\geqslant1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013030/how-to-prove-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1nn1n2-nk-fr)

We can also find some posts about the [finite sum](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cfrac1%7Bk(k%2B1)%5Ccdots(k%2Bs)%7D%24&p=1), for example [General formula for this sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)...(k+m)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003497/generall-formula-for-this-sum).

Comment: Damn it, i was so close $+1$

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Very nice! (+1)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thank you very much for your detailed answer. It's very kind of you.

Answer (score 9):

$${n \choose r}^{-1}$$

$$=\frac{r!(n-r)!}{n!}$$

$$=\frac{r\Gamma(r) \Gamma (n-r+1)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$

$$=rB(r,n-r+1)$$

$$=r \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-r} (1-x)^{r-1} dx$$

$$=r \int_{0}^{1} x^n x^{-r} (1-x)^{r-1} dx$$

Also note,

$$\sum_{n=r}^{\infty} x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n+r}=\frac{x^r}{1-x}$$

So that,

$$\sum_{n=r}^{\infty} {n \choose r}^{-1}$$

$$=r \int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{r-2} dx$$

$$=\frac{r}{r-1}$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=r}^\infty \binom{n}{r}^{-1}
&=
\sum_{n=r}^\infty \, (n+1)\int_0^1 x^{n-r} (1-x)^{r}\,dx
\\ &=
\int_0^1 \left( \sum_{n=r}^\infty (n+1)x^{n-r} \right) (1-x)^r \,dx
\\ &=
\int_0^1 \frac{1+r-rx}{(1-x)^2}  (1-x)^r \,dx
\\ &=
\frac{r}{r-1}
\end{align}