# Make sense of an equation of inverse binomials

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Wikipedias article about the binomial coefficient states:

"The series $${\displaystyle {\frac {k-1}{k}}\sum _{j=0}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{\binom {j+x}{k}}}={\frac {1}{\binom {x-1}{k-1}}}}$$ is convergent for $k ≥ 2$. This formula is used in the analysis of the German tank problem. It follows from $${\displaystyle {\frac {k-1}{k}}\sum _{j=0}^{M}{\frac {1}{\binom {j+x}{k}}}={\frac {1}{\binom {x-1}{k-1}}}-{\frac {1}{\binom {M+x}{k-1}}}}$$ which is proved by induction on $M$."

I am trying to find some meaning in the second formula. A proof through induction is fine, but it gives you little insight about where the formula comes from or what it means (combinatorically or as formula of probabilities).

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Comment: @ArtimisFowl This is the article that originally led me to the question above.

Comment: Here there are some proof that [$\sum_{n=r}^{\infty} {n \choose r}^{-1} = \frac{r}{r-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124113/a-proof-for-the-identity-sum-n-r-infty-n-choose-r-1-fracrr-1) maybe looking at those could bring some ideas about how to interpret this formula but can't say for sure

Comment: @danide This is helpful.